# IE is breaking span (inline) to side to another span in my div

Tags: html, css

I made a list with divs, that is displayed fine in *Opera*, but not in *IE*.

This is what is happening, in first scene, a line break for some rows, at last span from divs - that contains the class `shortcut`: http://i.imgur.com/D5wZEdb.png

These are the span and `.shortcut` styles:

```
.ui-context-menu .row span{
        font-size:16px;
        font-family:'Segoe Ui',Arial,sans-serif;
        font-weight:400
}
.ui-context-menu .row .shortcut{
        float:right;
        margin-left:40px;
        margin-right:15px
}
```

In the class `row`, I did:

```
.ui-context-menu .row{
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        height:25px;
        cursor:default;
        padding-right:18px
}
```

And the class `ui-context-menu` is a bit normal, but I add a property on to make overflow hidden.

The HTML may turn something so:

```
<div class="ui-context-menu" data-which="none" oncontextmenu="..." id="context-menu" style="display:none;left:8px;top:50px">
   <div class="row able" onmousedown="..." onclick="...">
      <div class="base">
         <div class="context">
            <span>
               Load
            </span>
            <span class="shortcut">
               CTRL+O
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is an quick fiddle for tests: http://jsfiddle.net/erpngfwv/2/

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you increase the min-width for `.ui-context-menu` to 200px in the fiddle, it works fine in all browsers. The default width of 125px is not enough to display the whole of the `row` div on 1 line, Apparently, Opera works harder to keep it one line (by doing an overflow) than IE.

Comment: @MrLister Yeah! This solved some problems, but it may rest some larger rows with longer text and be broken. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this class `".ui-context-menu .row span"` float

```
.ui-context-menu .row span{ 
    float: left;
    font-family: "Segoe Ui",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Solved! Thanks to make me not stuck at this part. :D